# How to create Dynamic date parameter in Quicksight?

Tags: parameters, amazon-quicksight, relative-date

I am new to Amazon-Quicksight. I tried different approaches but unable to find a solution, so posting it here.

I have a excel file having Actual sales data (including historic data) that gets updated daily. I have to create a day over day comparison report.

I have used relative filtering from current day to populate all the visuals like KPI, Top and Bottom movers etc.

My problem is as soon as the day changes, all the visuals go blank saying "NO Data".
I want that till the dataset is not replaced, it should show the comparison of Yesterday with day-before-yesterday, but as soon as data set is replaced it should show comparison of today with yesterday.

My approach was to create a dynamic date parameter, which will pick up max(date) from the dataset. But seems dynamic date parameter cannot be created. Also I am unable to use calculated field to pass a value to the parameter.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Regards
NC

Answer (score 0):

There is new functionality which allows you to set *today* or *beginning/ending* of *month/quater/year* as **default**.

See screenshot:

[Screenshot. QS, today as default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1VjQ.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32144152)